# How to maximise the activation of layers in TensorFlow DeepDream?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Basically I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/deepdream), but
I'm trying to load inception v5 from the downloaded pb file:

```
model_fn = 'tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'

graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession(graph=graph)
with tf.compat.v1.gfile.FastGFile(model_fn, 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

t_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(np.float32, name='input')
imagenet_mean = 117.0 
t_preprocessed = tf.expand_dims(t_input-imagenet_mean, 0)

op = sess.graph.get_operations()

tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, {'input': t_preprocessed})

# Maximize the activations of these layers
names = ['mixed4c', 'mixed5']
layers = [tf.keras.Model.get_layer(name).output for name in names]
```

The above code is giving me the folliowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 52, in <module>
layers = [tf.keras.Model.get_layer(name).output for name in names]
File "main.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
layers = [tf.keras.Model.get_layer(name).output for name in names]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2399, in get_layer
raise ValueError('Provide either a layer name or layer index.')
ValueError: Provide either a layer name or layer index.
```